# Can I wirelessly charge my laptop?

Tags: laptop, charger

I think I read somewhere that Dell was creating a wireless laptop charger but I haven't heard anything about it in the consumer market. Is this something that will be available in the next year? Are there other options?

Comment: There are [consumer-ready devices](http://www.powermat.com/) available, but I don't believe any have the power to charge a laptop battery yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dell is releasing a wireless *business* laptop that charges wirelessly, the Dell Latitude Z.  See

> [Tech Radar's article](http://www.techradar.com/news/mobile-computing/laptops/dell-s-wireless-charging-laptop-breaks-cover-639135)

and

> [Dell's Product Guide Details](http://www.dell.com/us/en/business/notebooks/laptop-latitude-z/pd.aspx?refid=laptop-latitude-z&cs=04&s=bsd)

It works with a dock that the laptop has to be on or near to charge wirelessly...it is expensive, around $1,800 and up!  To answer your question, in theory it is open to the consumer market, but only for this laptop, and those with a lot of $$$ and price range...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll be waiting a few more years for something more available and affordable.

Comment: yup...meanwhile, they have wireless charging for the iPhone/iPod Touch... and a few other *small* devices... :)