# How can I charge my laptop wirelessly?

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I wirelessly charge my laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/157176/can-i-wirelessly-charge-my-laptop)

Currently I'm using a wired charger for my laptop and it's boring me to carry that around with me everywhere.

I know of the wireless charging mat for phones, but what wireless solutions are there to charge laptops?

Comment: Reopened. This is actually an interesting question - thanks to all who helped touch it up! @Pacerier, if you can find some info on charging cell phones wirelessly (as you mentioned), that would be a useful link to include in your question.

Comment: Nice if we could recharge using the radio waves around us though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the wireless charging capabilities were implemented by the various locations you frequent, you would still have to carry around a charger of some sorts. Whether it's a mat similar to the ones that mobile phones can use, or the normal plug and charge.

As far as the charging mats go, the [Powermat](http://www.powermat.com/) offers a disc that you can set on the charging mat, which has a charging connector that plugs into the same place as your wired charger.

> ...there’s a special disc, called PC+,
>   which plugs into the notebook’s USB (not the USB, this was an error on the blogger's part; it seems to be the power port - same place you plug in your wired charger)
>   port. Set the disc down on the mat,
>   which, of course, is plugged into the
>   wall, and the notebook will start
>   charging. - [Latptop Mag](http://blog.laptopmag.com/video-wireless-charging-mat-powers-laptop)

The benefit of this being that you could just carry around the mat, instead of having to carry around a laptop charger and a mobile phone charger (also works for eReaders and portable gaming devices).

Comment: I don't quite get how you can charge a laptop  through USB and there's no mention of this on the powermat website on a cursory inspection

Comment: You are correct. I have edited my answer. I didn't think much about it as I was copying the quote. The video evidence shows them plugging it into the same port as if you had your wired charger.

Comment: Although Powermat is not directly connected so you could say it's "wireless", it isn't like you can wander around the house and have it charge your laptop or cellphone.  The term wireless is a bit misleading here.  It works like a transformer and needs to pretty much "on the mat" to work.